# How can I prevent Cufón from replacing text in elements under a certain class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, cufon

I'm using Cufón to replace text on a webpage, and I have the jQuery library loaded.  I'm trying to replace all instances of `<li>` elements (among others like `<p>`, et cetera), but only when they *don't* appear under a certain class.

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>This</li>
   <li>Should</li>
   <li>Be Replaced</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>So should</li>
    <li>this</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class='no-cufon'>
   <ul>
      <li>Don't replace this</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Note that most of my HTML is dynamic--otherwise I'd just go ahead and change the markup.

I'm using the command `Cufon.replace('*:not(.no-cufon) li');` to replace the text, but it's still targeting *all* `<li>` tags

In my developer console (Chrome 12), I get the following values with these jQuery selectors:

```
$("body *").length
11
$("body *:not(.no-cufon)").length
10
$("body * li").length
6
$("body *:not(.no-cufon) li").length
6
```

For some reason the `<li>` tags under the `no-cufon` class are still being matched in my final jQuery selector.

So if that doesn't work--what will?

Comment: Just a little note, `*` is only necessary when used by itself. Not that it relates to your issue.

Comment: Are you saying then that I can use `:not(.no-cufon)` instead of `*:not(.no-cufon)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)? With the following it selects all `li` elements that don't have `no-cufon` parents.

```
Cufon.replace($('li').filter(function(){
    if ($(this).parents('.no-cufon').length == 0) return true;
}));
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/prr4W/

Comment: Slightly more complicated than I had hoped (is there no way with pure CSS to do this?) but it fixes it.  Thanks!

Comment: @beanland I spent a good 10 minutes trying to get a CSS only solution which would work in any situation, but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

`body :not(.no-cufon) li` is matching the same `li`s as `body .no-cufon ul li`, because the `ul`s themselves are `:not(.no-cufon)`.

Try this instead:

```
Cufon.replace('body > :not(.no-cufon) > li, body > :not(.no-cufon) > ul > li');
```

Comment: It's pretty unreliable to try and exclude elements by ancestor with CSS selectors unless you have a very rigid and predictable HTML structure to apply styles to. I doubt my answer works for much beyond your sample HTML.

Comment: In fact maybe I should remove the "Try this" part of my answer, but that would leave it incomplete, wouldn't it?

Comment: Very helpful, and works perfectly, but, as you mention, doesn't expand beyond the sample, unfortunately. :(

Comment: @beanland: Well, I forgot you're using jQuery with Cufón. You can go with Niklas' answer, it'll work.